# JAVA - Writing NFC tag through USB NFC R/W in NDEF format with MIME

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard, nfc-p2p, open-nfc

Hi i got ACR122 USB NFC dongle which read and write the NFC Tag, how can i use USB NFC RW to write the data into NFC tag in NDEF format and MIME code (from PC) which could launch an app when contact a smart phone.I have tried writing tag with Smart Phone in Ndef format but i have doubt in using a external NFC RW to do the same, plz clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication protocols and the data format of NFC tags are standardized by the [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/). Their specifications are freely available on their web site.

As the ACR122 does not provide any abstraction layer for NFC tags (or even NDEF data), you would have to design the access to NFC tags on your own (the ACR122 API guide and the PN532 user manual will help you to find the right commands for that reader).